# Solidworks: Coincident or interfering geometry when saving assembly to STL

Tags: 3d-models, software

I'm using Solidworks to design parts to be 3d-printed.

I've noticed that if I'm making an assembly, where one part has features that touch other parts, then when I try to save that assembly as an STL for printing, I'll get a dialog from Solidworks saying "This assembly has coincident or interfering geometry that may be unsuitable for some rapid prototyping systems." If I save it, then this STL later causes problems when trying to print it.

What can I do? I'd like to be able to print my assemblies.

[Here is a very simple example assembly](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6fpzxcpwbmb48o/Interference%20test.SLDASM?dl=0) where you can see this phenomenon. Part 1 is just a simple cube, and part 2 is another simple cube that is flush with part 1.

Comment: What problem are you seeing when trying to print? You say you have issues but don't say what they are so no one can really help you. Also, I doubt many here have Solidworks or are going to download a viewer so you should post pictures instead of a Solidworks file.

Comment: @tjb1 When I view the STL in Simplify3D to get it ready for printing, sometimes some walls are invisible. If I try to print it, it doesn't print well. I think that what happens is that it treats the STL as two separate objects that have walls next to each other.

Comment: @RamRachum, at least Cura has option to merge nearby walls. Check your available settings.

Answer (score 1):

Solidworks has means for detection and eradication of these errors. If there's unwanted intersection, then you can either separate the parts or merge them (by saving assembly as a part). If you work with SLDPRTs, then use mating options correctly, avoid manual mating, make sure that the design of your components actually allows them to mate without intersections and you'll have no problems. If you work with parts that are loaded from STLs though, then you'll probably have a lot of these errors when trying to align parts. Solidworks can't work smoothly with STL models, alas, you'll need some other tool, MeshLab or something.

Answer (score 0):

When saving assembly as part, do not use the save external faces option. Exterior components is best option to use to try an aviod these problems.

*btw I dont have soldiworks, this is just some reseacrch I did*